# DocBin.merge method in spaCy

Tags: python, serialization, merge, spacy, doc

The following codes do not work, it is simply suggested in documentation [here](https://spacy.io/api/docbin#merge)!

```py
import spacy # V2.2
from spacy.tokens import DocBin # V2.2
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm') # V2.2

doc_bin1 = DocBin(attrs=["LEMMA", "POS"])
doc_bin1.add(nlp("Hello world"))
doc_bin2 = DocBin(attrs=["LEMMA", "POS"])
doc_bin2.add(nlp("This is a sentence"))
merged_bins = doc_bin1.merge(doc_bin2)
assert len(merged_bins) == 2
```

returns the following error:

```py
---> assert len(merged_bins) == 2
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

What's the solution?

Comment: try checking doc_bin1 instead of merged_bins

Comment: @Miguel Hi, no that doesn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a mistake in the example. `doc_bin1.merge(doc_bin2)` merges `doc_bin2` into `doc_bin1` and doesn't return a value. The final lines should be:

```
doc_bin1.merge(doc_bin2)
assert len(doc_bin1) == 2
```

Comment: I think probably they suppose to change the way it works, but they forgot it. because it is more convenient to actually it returns a new value instead of changing doc_bin1. Thank you